# React Material UI - Not possible to use themes other than 'light' and 'dark'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am working on a UI using React with Material UI (v5+). [In the docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/experimental-api/css-theme-variables/overview/), there is an `extendTheme` function you can use with `CssVarsProvider` to inject the MUI colors into CSS. In the docs in the same place, it says `You can create unlimited color schemes beyond light and dark.`.

My usage:

```
const themes = extendTheme({
  colorSchemes: {
    // basically a clone of light but with the background changed to bright red to make it obvious when it's loaded
    thirdTheme
  }
);

<CssVarsProvider theme={themes}>
... // App here
</CssVarsProvider>
```

However, when I create a third theme, and call `setMode('thirdTheme')`, it doesn't update the `data-mui-color-scheme` on `html` to be 'thirdTheme'. I know the theme is valid because if I manually update the data tag, then the colors change correctly. I was successfully able to switch between light and dark as well, so my usage of `setMode` appeared to be correct. I had basically just copied and pasted exactly what was in the docs - see below.

```
<Button
  onClick={() => {
    setMode(mode === 'thirdTheme'?
      'light'
      : 'thirdTheme');
    }}>
    {mode === 'thirdTheme'?
      'Turn light'
      :'Turn thirdTheme'}
</Button?
```

No matter what I do, it doesn't seem possible to add themes other than what you set to be light and dark. I even looked into the source code and found a few places where it seemed like it was specifically checking if the theme you tried to set was 'light' or 'dark'.

Am I missing something? Are the docs wrong, or is there some other way you're intended to set the theme to themes other than light and dark?

Edit: Third theme is created with the following -

```
const tempThemes = extendTheme();
const thirdTheme = _.cloneDeep(tempThemes.colorSchemes.light);
_.merge(thirdTheme.palette, {background: {default: '#ff0000'}});
thirdTheme.palette.mode = 'thirdTheme';
```

Comment: Where are your overrides?, Please see https://mui.com/material-ui/experimental-api/css-theme-variables/customization/

Comment: @DevMan Added it. I'm fairly certain it's a functional way of creating a theme, though, since I can manually update the data attribute to set it to medium, and I see the app colors change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out by reading the source code for material UI. Figured I'd answer since the solution isn't documented anywhere as far as I could find after several hours of searching. `setMode` definitely does force the mode you select to be 'light' or 'dark' as I thought. However, you can get an extra function which shortcuts those checks - in the docs, it has the following line:

```
  const { mode, setMode } = useColorScheme();
```

There is actually a third return, `setColorScheme`, that I found in `useCurrentColorScheme.js` where `setMode` and `mode` are returned. This can be taken from the return object:

```
  const { mode, setMode, setColorScheme } = useColorScheme();
```

This function will let you set your theme to other themes: `useColorScheme('thirdTheme')` changes the theme and saves the third theme to local storage as well for when you refresh.

Comment: Thanks. Based on your research, I could indeed find [setColorScheme](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-system/src/cssVars/useCurrentColorScheme.ts#L44), and indeed couldn't find any documentation about it. But I found in the docs the apparently experimental [`Experimental_CssVarsProvider`](https://mui.com/material-ui/experimental-api/css-theme-variables/usage/), which seems to be related.